# GCM Message gets stuck at "Accepted" state on GCM Server for some android devices

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

GCM Notifications not getting received on some android devices.

On monitoring the registration id of some those devices on GCM Diagnostics tool, I found that the messages are getting stuck at the "Accepted" state , i.e. the messages are arriving on the GCM server but are not forwarded to the device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the devices in which you are sending the message are registered. See [Registering Client Apps](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration).

Also, there are several factors why your device is stuck in the "Accepted" state and not sent on the device. See [Lifetime of a message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime) for further explanation.

> - If the device is connected but idle, the message will still be delivered right away unless the delay_while_idle flag is set to true. Otherwise, it will be stored in the GCM connection servers until the device is awake.
> - If the device is not connected to GCM, the message will be stored until a connection is established (again respecting the collapse key rules). When a connection is established, GCM will deliver all pending messages to the device, regardless of the delay_while_idle flag.

Comment: The devices are registered on the server. The code is working for some devices, i.e. some devices are receiving notifications while for some others, the messages are getting stuck at the Accepted state.

Comment: Even the delay_while_idle flag has not been set. So there should not be any delay in sending the message from GCM Server